# Using Ubuntu Advantage with Landscape

Tags: support

How to use [Ubuntu Advantage](https://ubuntu.com/advantage) with [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/)?

My understanding is that Ubuntu Advantage includes subscription to Landscape. I am trying the free subscription of Advantage which gives 3 machines subscription. I added one Ubuntu desktop (ua attach command) but that desktop was not automatically added to Landscape. I then added it to Landscape myself (landscape-config command) but it started using credits at $0.01/hour for using Landscape service.

Comment: This is something that I don't think fully functions as intended yet on Canonical's side.  I would suggest that you email Canonical and request three free slots per the UA-I 'free' tier.  `ua attach` does NOT set you up on Landscape, it's a separate account system that is linked to UA-I but not directly connected to `ua attach` which only attaches to the UA-I license and not Landscape.

Comment: (NOTE: I've prodded my connections at Canonical Community Team to poke it up the tree to the Canonical UA-I people to determine if this is something that they know is broken or if there's undocumented stuff that has to be done here)

Comment: I tried to contact canonical support but the page redirects to SSO error.

Comment: That's because you don't have a paid support subscription.  Let me prod my Canonical contacts.

Comment: @ThomasWard Were you able to reach out to your Canonical contacts?